Remove Junk characters in Flutter Web
I have TextField in this field im entering text like this ----This tablet cost you ₹200 im sending this text to API in payload it is going same, in response sometimes it is getting same but in sometimes it is converting as junk like this
   
    _model.textController3 ??= TextEditingController(text: utf8.decode(mystring.runes.toList()));

I have tried this method it is not working 100% because sometimes it is also breaking(not resolving junk characters).
